# Different behavior of pandas.Series operator /= in Python 2 vs Python 3

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-3.x, pandas, numpy

Here is the short python code where a really strange difference between anaconda2 and anaconda3 versions appears:

```
import pandas as pd


def div(x):
    to_sum = x['a']
    to_sum /= 2


def mul(x):
    to_sum = x['a']
    to_sum *= 2


a = pd.DataFrame(data=[[10.0, 20.0]], columns=['a', 'b'])
print('init:')
print(a)

div(a)
print('after div:')
print(a)

mul(a)
print('after mul:')
print(a)
```

When I run it this way:

```
echo "python3:" && \
~/work/Programs/Anaconda/anaconda3/bin/python3 tmp.py && \
echo && \
echo "python2:" && \
~/work/Programs/Anaconda/anaconda2/bin/python2 tmp.py
```

I get principally different results for different versions:

```
python3:
init:
      a     b
0  10.0  20.0
after div:
     a     b
0  5.0  20.0
after mul:
      a     b
0  10.0  20.0

python2:
init:
      a     b
0  10.0  20.0
after div:
      a     b
0  10.0  20.0
after mul:
      a     b
0  20.0  20.0
```

As of my understanding of python, the right behavior is demonstrated by python3 run. Why operator /= does not affect the function argument in python2? Even more, why then operator *= does affect it??!

I am using python and pandas from the official Anaconda's website. The versions are: (python 3.6.0 with pandas 0.19.2) and (python 2.7.13 with pandas 0.20.3)

Edit 1:
Trying this for integers (i.e `a = pd.DataFrame(data=[[10, 20]], columns=['a', 'b'], dtype='int')`) brings me:

```
python3:
init:
    a   b
0  10  20
after div:
     a   b
0  5.0  20
after mul:
      a   b
0  10.0  20

python2:
init:
    a   b
0  10  20
after div:
    a   b
0  10  20
after mul:
    a   b
0  20  20
```

Comment: I don't have python 2 to test but it seems like the basic difference between integer and real division. The first one changes the dtype so returns a copy and the second one has the same the dtype so returns a view. What happens if you try it on integers?

Comment: @ayhan Are you sure? I was of the understanding it had to do with pandas safeguarding against copies. I might need to revisit my answer.

Comment: @cᴏʟᴅsᴘᴇᴇᴅ Not completely sure because I couldn't test it on Python 2 but with `to_sum = to_sum // 2` Python 3 returns the same result as OP's Python 2 result.

Comment: @ayhan I see, I would trust you to know more about it than me, so feel free to write an answer :-) I've deleted mine.

Comment: @cᴏʟᴅsᴘᴇᴇᴅ Thanks. :) It would be better if someone could illustrate with Python 2 though. Do you have it? If so, please feel free to revise your answer with that.

Comment: @ayhan I've edited my question with results for integers. Data type in python3 is changed and in python2 is not changed, as it should to be, to my mind. But the numeric results are the same. Is that what you expect to see? As for `//=`, python2 and python3 are the same. However, It doesn't make the problem more clear to me. Could you provide some more detailed explanation?

Comment: @AlexanderKazakov It seems I was mistaken. My expectation was, if you apply the same procedure on an integer array, it would modify the array itself since the dtype is the same. However, it seems no matter the dtype is, if you apply floor division it creates a copy. I looked at `pd.Series._binop`, and `pd.Series.rfloordiv` but didn't see anything about it so this might be happening at the numpy level. I am adding the numpy tag.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This was [Pandas issue 12962](https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/issues/12962). An error in `pandas.core.ops` caused `__idiv__` to be missing the handling that would update the Series in place instead of returning a copy. Updating Pandas to at least 0.21 should fix things.